# reading and writing in files, char comparisons in C

Tags: c, io

[err message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Sis.png) 
[second code crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7QXF.jpg)

I have a strange problem happening. In the given code below, searching for the word "hell" in input.txt (which content is : hell, hellow, hello , hel ) , it prints me out the words : hell, hellow , hello in output.txt and that is my final task BUT only when I use a visual studio 2012 compiler. The code is runnable and executable there BUT I can't run it on a simple developer prompt, it can't be even compiled. Why is that? Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
  int main ( int argc, char **argv)
 {  //find ... -i ... -o ...
char *word;
word = new char;
FILE *readf = fopen ( argv[3] , "r" );
FILE *writef = fopen ( argv[5] , "w" );
while( ( fscanf(readf, "%s", word)!=EOF) )
{ 
      if(strstr(word, argv[1]) != NULL)
      {
          fprintf(writef,"%s\n",word);
      }
}
fclose(readf);
fclose(writef);
return 0;
```

}

That code over here works well, it compiles, executes, but it crashes and does nothing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ( int argc, char **argv)
{  //find ... -i ... -o ...

char *word = malloc(1024);
FILE *readf = fopen ( argv[3] , "r" );
FILE *writef = fopen ( argv[5] , "w" );
while( ( fscanf(readf, "%s", word)!=EOF) )
{ 
      if(strstr(word, argv[1]) != NULL)
      {
          fprintf(writef,"%s\n", word);
      }
}
fclose(readf);
fclose(writef);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I can't run it on a simple developer prompt, it can't be even compile". Please show us exactly how you are trying to compile and run it from the prompt. And exactly what happens including any error messages exactly as they appear.

Comment: This won't compile. Please post actual example.

Comment: That makes sense. I think that my compiler could read either C++ or C

Comment: OP's second example "works well ... but crashes" because `char word;` is a single character, not an array. What did you do with the compiler warnings?

Comment: While I think of it: it is a "schoolboy error" to fail to check the return values from `fopen`, `fscanf`, `malloc` etc. and the value of `argc` before indexing `argv[]`.

Comment: I updated my question. No errors when compiling, executing and the program just crashes.

Comment: On which line does the program crash? What have you done to identify the issues(s) you have with the program? What are the variable values at the point of the crash? Does changing the input file make any difference? What are the contents of the input file? And of the output file? Any errors reported from the I/O statements?

Comment: As commented above: change to `while ( ( fscanf(...)) == 1)`

Comment: Please don't post what you can post as text (code and error message) as image.

Comment: Is the second code `yo.c`? If so, check the number of arguments *before* using arguments and pass enough arguments to execute.

Comment: @user3121023 Why don't you use simple `char word[101];`? Practice of using `malloc()`?

Answer (score 1):

the main problem is that the operator `new` is only found in C++, not C.

Since only C header files are being used and I/O is being performed via `fscanf()` and `fprintf()`  this is C code not C++.

It just goes to show that `visual studio` leaves a lot to be desired.

NOTES:

1) The `argv[]` array should never be accessed beyond `argv[0]` until after checking `argc` to assure the desired command line parameters actually exist.

Because if the user did not enter the appropriate number of command line parameters, the the program will crash with a seg fault event.

when the proper number of command line parameters is not entered the program should output a USAGE message, similar to:

```
fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <parm1> <parm2> ...\n", argv[0]);
```

2) the proper way to use `fscanf()` for a loop control is to check the expected returned value (=number of format specifiers)  I.E.

```
while( 1 ==  fscanf(readf, "%s", word) )
```

Also, the '%s' format specifier will allow the user to overrun the input buffer.  strongly suggest these modifications

```
char word[100]
// eliminate this line: word = new char;
while( 1 ==  fscanf(readf, "%99s", word) )
```

3) when calling the function: `fopen()`, always check(!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful. similar to:

```
FILE *readf = NULL;
if( NULL == (readf = fopen ( argv[3] , "r" ) ) )
{ // then fopen failed
    perror( "fopen for input file failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, fopen for read successful

FILE *writef = NULL;
if( NULL == (readf = fopen ( argv[5] , "w" ) ) )
{ // then fopen failed
    perror( "fopen for output file failed" );
    fclose( readf );  // cleanup
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, fopen for write successful
```

However, the above calls to `perror()` could be replaced with calls to `fprintf()` similar to:

```
fprint( stderr, "fopen for read of %s failed due to: %s\n", argv[3], strerror( errno ) );
```